# Parallel topologies on a Prüfer group with the trivial group topology as the only group topology contained in both

Tags: topological-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number. A homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}\to \Bbb T$ induces a group topology $\mathcal T_f$ on $\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}$ with a base of neighborhoods $\mathcal N_f$ of $0$.

Are there one-to-one homomorphisms $f,g:\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}\to \Bbb T$ such that for every $A\in \mathcal N_f$ and $B\in \mathcal N_g$ we have $A+B=\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}$?

$\Bbb T$ is the circle group with Euclidean topology, but one can replace it with any other infinite nondiscrete Hausdorff topological abelian group if it makes the question simpler.

Comment: With the terminology of `On transversal group topologies` by D. Dikranjan, I'm looking for g-independent group topologies on a Prüfer group.

Comment: (I write $C_{p^\infty}$ for the Prufer group, to avoid confusion with $p$-adics) Well, tranversal means that $(f,g):C_{p^\infty}\to\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{T}$ has a dense image. Yes this exists and this is easy: indeed by Pontryagin duality it amounts to proving that there is an injective homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ into the $p$-adics $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @YCor: Do you mean g-independent by *traversal*? Btw, all I know about p-adic numbers is from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#p-adic_expansions). What is the injective homomorphism?

Comment: The definition in wikipedia is enough to figure out how to the existence of such a homomorphism.

Comment: @YCor Why are $f$ and $g$ g-independent iff  $\{(f(x),g(x))\mid x\in \Bbb Z_{p^\infty}\}$ is dense in $\Bbb T^2$? By definition, $f$ and $g$ are g-independent iff for every $A\in \mathcal N_f$ and $B\in \mathcal N_g$ we have $A+B=\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}$ or equivalently iff $\mathcal T_f$ and $\mathcal T_g$ contain the trivial group topology as the only group topology contained in both.

Comment: Let me prove only one direction (the one you need), in a wide generality (one group $C$, two topological groups $G_1,G_2$). Assume that the diagonal map $g=f_1\times f_2:C\to G_1\times G_2$ has a dense image, let $B_i$ be a symmetric neighborhood of $1$ in $G_i$ and $A_i=f_i^{-1}(B_i)$. Let's show $A_1A_2=C$. Let $x$ be an element of $C$. Then by density, we can approximate $(f_1(x),1)$ by the image of $g$. This implies that there exists $y\in C$ such that $(f_1(x)^{-1}f_1(y),f_2(y))\in B_1\times B_2$. Thus $x^{-1}y\in A_1$ and $y\in A_2$. Thus $x=y(x^{-1}y)^{-1}$ is in $A_1A_2$.